# Узнать имя текущего используемого wifi-драйвера

Tags: linux, wifi, драйвер

Как в Linux можно узнать имя текущего используемого wifi-драйвера?

Comment: для начала вам следует определиться с тем, что именно вы подразумеваете под термином «драйвер».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, скажите, пожалуйста, а какие есть варианты?

Comment: я подозреваю, что существует как минимум один вариант — то, что подразумеваете под этим словом **вы**.

Comment: Пока у Баракина какие-то приходы,  рекомендую глянуть вот сюда: *ls -l /sys/class/net/<iface>/device/driver/module*. *<iface>*, например, *eth0*.

Comment: @0andriy, спасибо, этот вариант проще чем lsmod

Answer (score 1):

Если устройство pci, то тут все просто

```
lspci -k
```

а дальше в списке ищите свое устройство и видите драйвера/модули.

Если нет, тогда lsmod и изучать.

Comment: А если драйвер вкомпилирован в ядро? Нет, всё гораздо проще